# Upload data to website

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am currently working on a web page for my website. The purpose of my page is to display my employee's daily statistics. For example, their performance and customer satisfaction. I will display this data as follows.

```
<body>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Bob</td> <!--Name-->
    <td>96%</td> <!--Customer Satisfaction-->
    <td>2%</td> <!--48 hour callback-->
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Jack</td> <!--Name-->
    <td>98%</td> <!--Customer Satisfaction-->
    <td>5%</td> <!--48 hour callback-->
  </tr>
</table>

</body>
```

I want to have these statistics added daily. I know I can manually upload the numbers every night, but this seems to be tedious as I have 30+ employees. My question is, is there an easier way to upload data to an html file? Is there any way to send an email to a web server, have the code scan for data, and take those numbers and automatically update those numbers to where they need to go? Any suggestions or ideas would be greatly appreciated! Thank you.

Comment: you can create a file from where your webpage collect the data, and for the update purpose you may create a `cron` for update daily. I am not very familiar with it but i know it.

Comment: @FrayneKonok *`cron`

Comment: So have a file collect the data from an email, and then have a cron job run another php file which uploads the data onto my site?

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following as a solution

1. Use watchman tool (https://github.com/facebook/watchman) to keep a watch on the data file where you update data which will upload the file to your website as and when you update that file.
2. In your website write an endpoint to handle the file upload which will save uploaded file, parse data from it and save it in the required way to display it whenever someone visits your website!

**EDIT**

For further information on using watchman you can refer [this link](http://vitiy.info/easy-way-to-auto-upload-modifications-live-development/)

Comment: Can you add an example based on watchman, to support your answer.

Comment: Perhaps you could checkout http://vitiy.info/easy-way-to-auto-upload-modifications-live-development/

Comment: Thanks, that was helpful.

Comment: @GauravDave why was this answer downvoted?

Comment: @Bhargav Why are you asking me, I didn't down voted.

Comment: @GauravDave Sorry I tagged you by mistake lol

Answer (score 1):

Yes. There are many many ways to do this.

The most standard way would be to have your employees upload the data to your server and have the data entered in a database, and then use PHP to render HTML based on the database contents.

## Task 1 - Get Data to Server

Your first task is to get the data on the server. **Email is not going to be the way to do this.** Emails use the SMTP/S and IMAP protocols which can be very tricky and require notoriously buggy (and bulky) libraries to handle. You will be much happier using the very user friendly HTTP/S protocol to POST the data.

Basically an HTTP post works like this. You include an [HTML form](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp) on some webpage where your employees can submit this data to your server. It will look something like this.

```
<form action="data_receiving_endpoint.php" method="post">
    Username:<br/>
    <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Please input your full name."/>
    Password:<br/>
    <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Please input your password."/>
    How You Feel About Working for Me Today:<br/>
    <input type="text" name="feelings" placeholder="Please input your feelings."/>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

You can learn about forms more on your own but what you should notice here is

1. The `action` attribute points toward a page on your server. You may read `action="data_receiving_endpoint.php` more clearly as `<yourhostname>/data_receiving_endpoint.php`.
2. The `method` attribute specifies an HTTP method to use - POST in this case.
3. Each input has a `name` attribute that uniquely identifies it.
4. One of the inputs has `type="submit"`. This will be a button that performs the `action` when clicked.

When the user clicks "Submit" the browser will make an HTTP POST request to your server. The request will contain a payload that looks something like this.

```
username=Jimmy%20John&password=iamjimmyjohn&feelings=You%27re%20the%20worst%20boss%20in%20the%20world!
```

The "%xx" symbols are hex codes for characters not supported in HTML form data. When translated this data becomes

```
username=Jimmy John
&
password=iamjimmyjohn
&
feelings=You're the worst boss in the world!
```

## Task 2 - Record Data in Server

Your next task is to take your employee's data and store it somewhere usable, like a database. For this example I'll assume you'll be using [MySQLi](https://www.mysql.com/), which TBH you probably will be.

What happens next needs to happen at the URI referenced by `action` in your HTML form. You need to create a PHP file at `/data_receiving_endpoint.php`. This will be a script file that will be executed to handle any incoming requests.

This PHP file needs to take the post data and submit it to your MySQLi database. It will look something like this. If you aren't familiar with [SQL (Standard Query Language)](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/default.asp) syntax you will want to brush up on it.

```
<?php
    $dbhostname = 'localhost';
    $adminuser = 'thebossman';
    $adminpwd = 'secretPassword';
    $dbname = 'thebossmansdatabase';
    // connect to your database (it's its own server in a way)
    $connection = new mysqli($dbhostname, $adminuser, $adminpwd, $dbname);
    if ($connection->connect_error) {
        // if connection failed then abort
        header('HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error');
        die('failed to establish connection');
    }
    // image you have a table named "DataTable"
    // first step is to validate the user's password
    // we can use variables from the post data by calling $_POST['variable name']
    $verifyCommand = 'SELECT * FROM DataTable WHERE username='.$_POST['username'];
    $result = $connection->query($verifyCommand);
    if ($result->num_rows == 0) {
        // the user is unknown, you should abort
        header('HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden');
        die('user was not recognized.');
    }
    $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
    if ($row['password'] != $_POST['password']) {
        // the user cannot be authenticated
        header('HTTP/1.1 404 Unauthorized');
        die('The user was not authenticated.');
    }
    // now the user is authorized and you should update the database
    $updateCommand = 'UPDATE DataTable SET feelings='.$_POST['feelings'].' WHERE username='.$_POST['username'];
    if ($connection->query($updateCommand) !== TRUE) {
        // database update failed
        header('HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error');
        die('database update failed');
    }
    // you're done. you can close the connection.
    $connection->close();
php?>
<!-- REMEMBER THE USER WILL BE SENT TO THIS PAGE SO THERE SHOULD BE SOME HTML BELOW THIS -->
```

Now you have the user's posted data stored safely in your server.

## Task 3 - Generate HTML from Database Info

This is what PHP was made for. Here you will design a script that creates a webpage dynamically based on the contents of a database in your server.

It's a very simple process. All that happens is that any text surrounded by `<?php`...`php?>` will be executed before the HTML is sent to the user. You use the `echo` method to print a line of text to the HTML file.

At the start of your page you should have something like this

```
<?php
    $connection = new mysqli('localhost', 'thebossman', 'secretPassword', 'thebossmansdatabase');
    if ($connection->connect_error) {
        header('HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error');
        die('failed to connect to database');
    }
php?>
```

You will then have your connection available the entire time the script executes. Just remember at the bottom you need to put

```
<?php
    $connection->close();
php?>
```

Generating the display is not difficult from this point on. Basically you just come up with a systematic way to fill in data. For example instead of

```
<table>
    <head>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Feelings</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>Jimmy John</td>
        <td>You&#39;re the worst boss in the world!</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Jenna Whatever</td>
        <td>I don&#39;t mind you.</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

You can instead do this to generate the page on the fly.

```
<table>
    <head>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Feelings</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
<?php
    $result = $connection->query('SELECT username, feelings FROM DataTable');
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo '<tr><td>';
        // remember to escape special charaters
        echo htmlspecialchars($row['username']);
        echo '</td><td>';
        echo htmlspecialchars($row['feelings']);
        echo '</td></tr>';
    }
php?>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Which is basically what you asked for.